# How to set a UUID in protocol buffers?

Tags: python-2.7, protocol-buffers

My code receives and decodes a protocol buffer. This code is supposed to generate a unique ID and update the protocol buffer's `_id` field which is of type `UUID`. However, I can't figure out how to set it.

How is this done?

Comment: There is no built-in `UUID` type, so it must be a message type. Look for the definition of `UUID` in your `.proto` file or the files it imports.

Comment: Yep, it's a Message. Internally it is pair of int32s, if memory serves.

Comment: Then you need to manipulate it like any other sub-message. There is lots of documentation on sub-messages. If you have a more specific problem not obviously covered by the docs, could you edit your question to clarify? Also include the definition of `UUID` in your question.